# Add Ampersand to XmlElement

Tags: c#, xml

I am creating several XmlElements used in a larger XML Document.

```
XmlElement thisElement = xmlSearchParameters.CreateElement("value");
thisElement.InnerXml = this.searchParameters[key];
```

This works well for most instances, but if the value of searchParameters[key] happens to include an & symbol, I get one of the two following errors:

Unexpected end of file has occurred. Line 1, position 1. - if value is ONLY &

An error occurred while parsing EntityName. Line 1, position 7. - if value contains & mixed with other text.

What is the prefered way of including & and any other special symbols in an XmlElement? I suspect there must be a better way than just replacing & with something else (some sort of XmlFormat method???).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why do you use `InnerXml` in the first place? It's supposed to be used if you have some *valid* markup in unparsed string form, and want to insert it there. For plain text, use `InnerText`:

```
thisElement.InnerText = this.searchParameters[key];
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I haven't worked with XmlElement much in the past and this is just how the code was setup when I started working on it. Changing to use InnerText solves my problem.

Answer (score 4):

If you use InnerXml you have to guarantee that text value is valid xml.
Use InnerText property instead of InnerXml.

Answer (score 2):

[SecurityElement.Escape](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securityelement.escape(VS.80).aspx) will replace the less than, greater than, quote, apostrophe, and ampersand symbols, which is probably all you need.